# Query XML values stored in attributes & import into dataset using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, dataset

I am new to c# in general and new to parsing xml.  I have an xml stream that I am getting from a web service that has values in attributes that I want to load into my SQL Server using a dataset/datatable.  I am having a hard time getting the data in the structure that I want to import into SQL.

I would like to pull the data (for each  into a tables in the following structure:

Columns: bounce_date cancellation_mailing_instance_id cancellation_message cancellation_date email, etc.

Rows: bounce_date "value" cancellation_mailing_instance_id "value" cancellation_message "value" cancellation_date "value" email "value", etc.

So far all I can accomplish is getting all the data into rows.  I would like to create the column headers based on  , etc

...and the Rows based on "Value" "Value", etc.

My XML is coming over as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<GridResponse xmlns="http://sample.sample.net/aapi/2009/08/">
<Brand id="12345">ACME</Brand>
<User>asample</User>
<Grids>
<Grid type="subscriber">
<Record row="1">
<Fields>
<Field element="bounce_date"/>
<Field element="cancellation_mailing_instance_id"/>
<Field element="cancellation_message"/>
<Field element="cancellation_date">2018-03-21T16:00:25.7670000Z</Field>
<Field element="email"/>
<Field element="is_repeated_bouncer">0</Field>
<Field element="is_unsubscriber">1</Field>
<Field element="modified_date">2018-03-21T16:00:29.6500000Z</Field>
<Field element="service_since_date">2018-03-21T13:45:50.2800000Z</Field>
<Field element="user_id"/>
<Field element="subscriber_upload_id"/>
<Field element="imis_name_id"/>
</Fields>
</Record>
<Record row="2">
<Fields>
<Field element="bounce_date"/>
<Field element="cancellation_mailing_instance_id"/>
<Field element="cancellation_message"/>
<Field element="cancellation_date"/>
<Field element="email">xxxxx@sample.org</Field>
<Field element="is_repeated_bouncer">0</Field>
<Field element="is_unsubscriber">0</Field>
<Field element="modified_date">2018-03-21T14:07:32.1530000Z</Field>
<Field element="service_since_date">2018-03-21T14:07:32.1530000Z</Field>
<Field element="user_id"/>
<Field element="subscriber_upload_id"/>
<Field element="imis_name_id"/>
</Fields>
</Record>
<Record row="3">
<Fields>
<Field element="bounce_date"/>
<Field element="cancellation_mailing_instance_id"/>
<Field element="cancellation_message"/>
<Field element="cancellation_date"/>
<Field element="email">xxxxx2@sample.org</Field>
<Field element="is_repeated_bouncer">0</Field>
<Field element="is_unsubscriber">0</Field>
<Field element="modified_date">2019-04-22T20:03:33.9700000Z</Field>
<Field element="service_since_date">2019-04-22T20:03:33.9700000Z</Field>
<Field element="user_id"/>
<Field element="subscriber_upload_id"/>
<Field element="imis_name_id"/>
</Fields>
</Record>
</Grid>
</Grids>
</GridResponse>
```

So far I am trying Linq To XML.  I would be eternally grateful if someone could provide a little code sample to get me started!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

He is some real simple Xml Linq that reads results into a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication110
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            Dictionary<int, List<string>> results = doc.Descendants(ns + "Record")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("row"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Descendants(ns + "Field").Select(z => (string)z.Attribute("element")).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you jdweng!   This is very helpful.  If you don't mind I am trying to view the contents of the list.  I can only get the row and Field but am unable to view the Field value "z".

I am doing the following:

 foreach (var x in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Key);

                foreach (var y in x.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(y);
                                                           

                }
                               
                
            }

Comment: I get the following results:

1
bounce_date
cancellation_mailing_instance_id
cancellation_message
cancellation_date
email
is_repeated_bouncer
is_unsubscriber
modified_date
service_since_date
user_id
subscriber_upload_id
imis_name_id
2
bounce_date
cancellation_mailing_instance_id
cancellation_message
cancellation_date
email
is_repeated_bouncer
is_unsubscriber
modified_date
service_since_date
user_id
subscriber_upload_id
imis_name_id